# Why does evhttp_request_get_connection() always return NULL?

Tags: http, null, connection, request, libevent

In the following example program:

```
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/http.h>
#include <assert.h>

void response_cb(struct evhttp_request* req, void *arg) {
    assert(evhttp_request_get_response_code(req)<400);/* passes */
    assert(evhttp_request_get_connection(req));/* FAILS ??? */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct event_base* ev_base;
    struct evhttp_connection *http_conn;
    struct evhttp_request *req;

    ev_base = event_base_new();
    http_conn = evhttp_connection_base_new(ev_base, NULL, "google.com", 80);
    req = evhttp_request_new(response_cb, NULL);

    evhttp_make_request(http_conn, req, EVHTTP_REQ_GET, "/");

    event_base_dispatch(ev_base);
    return -1;
}
```

in response_cb the first assert passes, as expected, but the seconds fails i.e. evhttp_request_get_connection(req) returns NULL. Why is that?

The documentation for evhttp_request_get_connection claims:

> Returns the connection object associated with the request or NULL.

But I still have a connection. I do not dispose of it anywhere.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug or just some obscure feature?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a pointer to the connection in the response callback, because the connection has already been released (closed, or kept open fore reuse if HTTP keepalive is enabled).

You can see in evhttp_connection_done() (http.c, around lines 780 to 817) that the response callback is called after the request's connection field (evcon) has been set to NULL. I do agree that the evhttp API is not very clear, though.

Comment: keep-alive doesn't seem to have anything to do with this issue.
According to http.c : evhttp_connection_done() req->evcon = NULL is set for all outgoing connections not only for the non-keep-alive connections.

Comment: Well, it was an example, not a thorough check of all cases where the connection might be reused. Sorry if it seemed that way.